# Change email verification error message Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.7 email verification. When I try to log in it says - `Your email address is not verified`
http://joxi.ru/n2YqYJaIo1XGO2
I need to change this message to another language but could not find where to change.
In resources/lang - there are validations and other messages but could not find this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

### **Better solution, use this instead.**

---

You'll have to implement a custom middleware which you can create with the artisan command:

`php artisan make:middleware EnsureEmailIsVerified`

EnsureEmailIsVerified.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;

class EnsureEmailIsVerified
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
     public function handle($request, Closure $next)
     {
         if (! $request->user() ||
             ($request->user() instanceof MustVerifyEmail &&
             ! $request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail())) {
             return $request->expectsJson()
                     ? abort(403, 'YOUR CUSTOM ERROR HERE')
                     : Redirect::route('verification.notice');
         }

         return $next($request);
     }
}
```

You will have to map the `verified` key in your kernel file to the new middleware.

app\Http\Kernel.php (down at the bottom):

```
    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \App\Http\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class, // the changed line
    ];
```

### **Original answer**

---

I used Notepad++'s find in file function and scanned all the files in my Laravel project for: "Your email is not verified"

It came up with one match in:

`\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified.php`

Which is this file:

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Auth\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;

class EnsureEmailIsVerified
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (! $request->user() ||
            ($request->user() instanceof MustVerifyEmail &&
            ! $request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail())) {
            return $request->expectsJson()
                    ? abort(403, 'Your email address is not verified.')
                    : Redirect::route('verification.notice');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I'm **guessing** that if you change this line: `? abort(403, 'Your email address is not verified.')`

To whatever you want the error to be, for example: `? abort(403, 'Please, verify your email.')`

That it will display that. (Please confirm this if you try it).

---

There's one minor issue with this solution. Since your `.gitignore` file tells git to ignore the vendor folder, it won't be pushed to an external repo when pushing.

You will need to change the `.gitignore` file.

Laravel updates will **also** revert this change, so you will have to rewrite it, there's a better solution at the top of this answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this path in your laravel application "\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified.php" 
You will find the error message "Your email address is not verified" here on in `

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (! $request->user() ||
            ($request->user() instanceof MustVerifyEmail &&
            ! $request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail())) {
            return $request->expectsJson()
                    ? abort(403, 'Your email address is not verified.')
                    : Redirect::route('verification.notice');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Comment: But if I update composer , these changes will be overridden?

Comment: @TrueCode correct. You're best writing a custom middleware which mimics this functionality and swapping it out in the route middleware array in `app/Http/Kernel.php`.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the file directly as others have said, but when Laravel updates, this file will be overridden by Composer.

You should make a new Middleware class with the contents of the `EnsureEmailIsVerified` class, and change the declaration of the 'verified' middleware in the `app/Http/Kernel.php` file:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    // change to:
    'verified' => \Your\Custom\Middleware::class,
];
```

You could even make the abort message use a lang file, so you can change it in future.